# Replace special character with sed

Tags: shell, sed, sh

I'm trying to replace a special character with sed, the character are Þ to replace for ;

The lines of the file are, for example;

```
0370ÞA020Þ4000011600ÞRED USADOÞ0,00Þ20190414
0370ÞA020Þ4000011601ÞRED USADOÞ0,00Þ20190414
0370ÞA020Þ4000011602ÞRED USADOÞ0,00Þ20190414
```

Thanks!

Edit

Its worked and solved.

Thanks!!!

Comment: `sed 's/Þ/;/g' infile`

Comment: `tr 'Þ' ';' < old.txt > new.txt`

Comment: @nbari that was my first thought too but see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55728341/1745001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - simple substitution work for me

```
sed 's/Þ/;/g'
```

Comment: yes, worked :DD thanks, and if i need save the result would it be something like this?

`
 's/Þ/;/g' file4.csv >> file4.csv'
`

Comment: `sed 's/Þ/;/g' infile > outfile` replace `outfile`. if you use `>>` result is appended to `outfile`. Consider accepting the answer if it's working for you (tick under downvote) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That's the job `tr` was created to do but look at these results:

```
$ tr 'Þ' ';' < file
0370;;A020;;4000011600;;RED USADO;;0,00;;20190414
0370;;A020;;4000011601;;RED USADO;;0,00;;20190414
0370;;A020;;4000011602;;RED USADO;;0,00;;20190414

$ sed 's/Þ/;/g' < file
0370;A020;4000011600;RED USADO;0,00;20190414
0370;A020;4000011601;RED USADO;0,00;20190414
0370;A020;4000011602;RED USADO;0,00;20190414
```

`tr` seems to consider every `Þ` as being 2 duplicate characters - sed may think the same but while `tr` is converting a set of chars to a set of chars, sed is converting a regexp to a string and so even if it considers `Þ` to be 2 characters wide it'll still do what you want. So just an interesting warning about trying to use `tr` to replace non-ASCII characters - YMMV!

Comment: Interesting, working for me on macOS & FreeBSD, in Linux option `-s` may be needed `tr -s  'Þ' ';' < file`

Comment: @nbari You can't use `-s` because then it'll replace multiple contiguous `Þ`s in the input with one `;`. I'm using cygwin FWIW.

Comment: Right because this particular example doesn't contain a line like `fooÞÞbar` which should become `foo;;bar` but if you use `tr -s` will become `foo;bar`.

Comment: however good catch to take into account when creating a script and thinking about portability

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd' file, try gnu sed:

```
sed -E 'y/Þ/;/' d
```